# Taking screenshots using pyscreenshot

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I just want to create a screenshot with python. In the internet it's written that I need to use the pyscreenshot lib with the pillow lib. So I installed both and imported them into the py file.

Finally I came to this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

img = ImageGrab.grab()
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray', interpolation='bicubic')
plt.show()
```

This gives me no error, however, the screenshot does not popup.

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: it gives me no error at all :(

Answer (score 6):

So i found the problem...

istead of:

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
```

i did:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
```

thats all.

Here is my final code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import ImageGrab

img = ImageGrab.grab()


plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray', interpolation='bicubic')
plt.show()
```

hopefully that helped you if you have the same problem as i had.

Comment: hi @niceManComp Can I use pyscreenshot for taking screenshots of webpages while running the script?

Comment: Just clarification for people viewing this answer:
ImageGrab is only valid for windows and Mac platforms.

Comment: Ramast is correct. Any idea how to do this in Linux?